# Django REST Framework: apply filter to list view but not detail view

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

With Django REST Framework is there a way, when using a `ModelViewSet`, to filter only the list results but not the detail results?

I have a list of objects that have an owner and I only want users to see the objects they own when they access the objects list. For that purpose I implemented a new filter backend based on `rest_framework.filters.BaseFilterBackend`, which works fine for the list.

The problem arises when I try to access an object that doesn't belong to my user: I get a "404 not found" instead of a "403 forbidden".

In other words, filtering seems to be applied not only to the list but also to the detail view. Is there a way to change this, so that I get the expected 403 when accessing an object which I'm not authorized to see?

I already have a permission class in place which prevents a user from seeing objects he doesn't own but it's not even being called unless I comment out the `filter_backends` property on the viewset class.

Another way to think about this is that I only want to list objects that the user has permission to see.

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if `pk` is in the view kwargs

```
class MyFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if 'pk' not in view.kwargs:
            queryset = queryset.filter(...)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rest_framework` exception that you'd want to raise is `PermissionDenied` to return a **403**, so do this instead of `get_object_or_404`.

Apply the logic you want, and raise the exception when the User should not be at that DetailView endpoint.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    model = User

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            return self.model.objects.filter(foo='bar').get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoestNotExist:
            # can't find the User based upon the filter foo='bar'
            # that represents a object permissions filter
            raise PermissionDenied("message to accompany the 403 error if desired")
```

Comment: `self.model` doesn't seem to be a valid property of the `ModelViewSet` class, I had to use the model class itself instead (edited your answer to reflect that). Also, this would require me to override the `retrieve` method for all the classes I want to make this change in, which is quite cumbersome since I have a lot of them. Even more importantly, it seems that this would raise a 403 even for objects that don't exist, not a 404 as it should. It's the exact opposite of the situation I'm trying to avoid. I was hoping for a better way to do it.